# Vue Show more in deep array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add a "show-more" button to an array(v-for) of an array (v-for).

```html
<li v-for="(recruiter, key) in recruiters.data" :key="recruiter.id">
  <div v-if="recruiter.cities" >
    <div v-if="recruiter.cities.length <= 5 || recruiter.id in cities_expand">
      <a :href="'/rekryterare/' + city.slug" v-for="(city, index) in recruiter.cities">{{ city.name }}</a>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <template v-for="(city, index) in recruiter.cities">
        <template v-if="index+1 <= 4">
          <a :href="'/rekryterare/sverige/' + city.slug" >{{ city.name }}</a>
        </template>
      </template>
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="cities_expand.push(recruiter.id)" >...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Basically if there is more than 4 items in `recruiter.cities` -> show 4 items + "show more"

However - the `recruiter.id in cities_expand` does not work/update?

I'm sure there is a better way of solving this - but nothing else came to mind :)
Any ideas?

Comment: I do not see any better solution related to Vue or js in general

Comment: Thanks - but the strange thing is.... it is not working. Even though the cities_expand has the recruiter.id it is not showing all cities. Even stranger: if i spam-click the "show more" it will eventually update..

Comment: Please share a reproductible exemple

Comment: are you talking about the rendering of cities_expand in a separate bit of code you're not showing? as its obvious, the `recruiter.id in cities_expand` line won't render again as your not changing `recruiters.data` so it won't trigger this loop again

Comment: a hack would be `:key="recruiter.id + JSON.stringify(cities_expand)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspect that the problem is the use of the js [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator. The `in` operator checks if an object has a key in the object. **It does not check if an array has a value**.

So when doing `recruiter.id in cities_expand`, this checks if `recruiter.id` is a key in the array `cities_expand`. The keys of an array are the array indices.

This would explain why spam clicking will work because if the `recruiter.id` is e.g. 9, then `recruiter.id in cities_expand` will only be true if `cities_expand` has key `9` i.e. **length 10**. Which means you would have to click `...` 10 times.

Changing

```
<div v-if="recruiter.cities.length <= 5 || recruiter.id in cities_expand">
```

to

`<div v-if="recruiter.cities.length <= 5 || cities_expand.indexOf(recruiter.id) > -1 ">`

should do the trick.

---

In terms of an alternative solution, I would encapsulate the inner loop in a component and use a computed value for the list. E.g.

Component `RecruiterCities`:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="displayCities" >
    <a :href="'/rekryterare/' + city.slug" v-for="(city, index) in displayCities" :key="index">{{ city.name }}</a>
    <a v-if="!showExpanded && totalCities > maxDisplayCities" href="#" @click.prevent="showExpanded = true" >...</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    recruiterCities: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return []
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showExpanded: false,
      maxDisplayCities: 4
    }
  },
  computed: {
    totalCities() {
      return (this.recruiterCities && this.recruiterCities.length) || 0;
    },
    displayCities() {
      if (!this.recruiterCities) {
        return [];
      }

      if (this.showExpanded || this.recruiterCities.length <= this.maxDisplayCities) {
        return this.recruiterCities;
      }

      return this.recruiterCities.slice(0, this.maxDisplayCities);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and to use it:

```
  <li v-for="(recruiter, key) in recruiters.data" :key="recruiter.id">
    <RecruiterCities :recruiter-cities="recruiter.cities"/>
  </li>
```